# Erros na Alteração de tabelas do PostGre para incrementar as FKs

Tags: sql, banco-de-dados, postgresql, tabela-banco-de-dados

As tabelas são criadas numa boa, entretanto fico obtendo erros e não consigo alterar as tabelas e incrementar as Foreign Keys.

```
CREATE TABLE Funcionario(
    IDFuncionario SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
    Nome VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
    Sexo VARCHAR(1) NOT NULL,
    Data_Admissao TIMESTAMP,    
    Matricula VARCHAR(10) UNIQUE NOT NULL,
    Salario DECIMAL(10,2) NOT NULL
);

CREATE TABLE TELEFONE(
    IDTelefone SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
    Telefone VARCHAR(30),
    Celular VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL
);

CREATE TABLE Acesso(
    IDAcesso SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
    Usuario VARCHAR(10) UNIQUE NOT NULL,
    Senha VARCHAR(10) UNIQUE NOT NULL
);

CREATE TABLE Setor(
    IDSetor SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
    Nome_Setor VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL
);

CREATE TABLE Endereco(
    IDEndereco SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
    Cep VARCHAR(8) NOT NULL,
    Estado VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
    Cidade VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
    Bairro VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
    Rua VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
    Numero VARCHAR(3) NOT NULL,
    Complemento VARCHAR(10)
);

ALTER TABLE Setor
ADD FOREIGN KEY (FK_Funcionario) REFERENCES Funcionario(IdFuncionario);

ALTER TABLE Funcionario
ADD FOREIGN KEY(FK_Cargo)REFERENCES Nome_Cargo(IDCargo);

ALTER TABLE SETOR
ADD FOREIGN KEY (FK_Funcionario) REFERENCES Nome_Setor(IDSetor);
```

Comment: "incrementar" seria criar as chaves estrangeiras?

Comment: as chaves primárias já são criadas como o tipo SERIAL, elas já são "incrementadas"

Comment: @Danizavtz FK é a abreviação de foreign key (chave estrangeira).

Answer (score 0):

Na verdade em seu script ficou faltando adicionar a coluna e o tipo utilizado na Foreign Key.

Se deseja adicionar uma chave estrangeira via um comando de alter table, vai ter que adicionar a coluna com o mesmo tipo da chave estrageira da tabela em que é feita referência na declaração da chave estrangeira.

Segue um exemplo:

```
CREATE TABLE Setor(
    IDSetor SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
    Nome_Setor VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL
);
```

Neste caso temos a tabela setor, devemos portanto adicionar primeiramente a coluna `FK_Funcionario` na tabela `Setor`.

Para fazer este procedimento então é necessário usar o comando ALTER TABLE ADD COLUMN. Você pode ver a sintaxe e documentação deste comando na [documentação](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-altertable.html).

```
ALTER TABLE Setor ADD COLUMN FK_Funcionario INTEGER;
```

Repare que aqui neste trecho de código eu declarei o valor da chave estrangeira como INTEGER, você pode se perguntar porque eu escolhi este tipo. Visto que a declaração de tipo na tabela funcionário é do tipo SERIAL.

Após adicionar essa coluna, será possível executar o comando que deseja para adicionar a restrição da chave estrangeira à tabela SETOR:

```
ALTER TABLE Setor 
ADD FOREIGN KEY (FK_Funcionario) REFERENCES Funcionario(IdFuncionario);
```

A modificação feita aqui é apenas na tabela `setor` mas vai precisar fazer em todas as tabelas em que deseja adicionar a chave estrangeira.

#### Como descobrir o tipo de dado da coluna referenciada da chave estrangeira?

Para "saber" o tipo correto é necessário descrever o estado atual da tabela (que é referenciada na Foreign Key), para verificar qual o tipo correto. Para fazer este procedimento utilizamos o comando `describe` (que pode ser executado através do comando: <kbd>\d funcionario</kbd>).
Ao executar este comando podemos listar o tipo desta coluna, desta forma não vamos ter erro ao associar as chaves estrangeiras.

```
=# \d funcionario;
                                               Table "public.funcionario"
    Column     |            Type             | Collation | Nullable |                      Default                       
---------------+-----------------------------+-----------+----------+----------------------------------------------------
 idfuncionario | integer                     |           | not null | nextval('funcionario_idfuncionario_seq'::regclass)
 nome          | character varying(50)       |           | not null | 
 sexo          | character varying(1)        |           | not null | 
 data_admissao | timestamp without time zone |           |          | 
 matricula     | character varying(10)       |           | not null | 
 salario       | numeric(10,2)               |           | not null |
```

#### Uma maneira equivalente de chegar ao mesmo resultado

Uma maneira equivalente de chegar ao mesmo resultado é modificando a definição de criação da tabela `Setor`.

```
CREATE TABLE Setor(
    IDSetor SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
    Nome_Setor VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
    FK_Funcionario INTEGER,
    FOREIGN KEY (FK_Funcionario) REFERENCES Funcionario(IdFuncionario);
);
```